# How to instantiate and populate class variables using a list?

Tags: python, list, class, pydantic

I would like to instantiate variables within a class using a list. This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
my_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'mango']
my_object = my_class(my_list)
vars(my_object) => {'apple': 'apple', 'banana': 'banana', 'mango': 'mango'}

my_list = ['pear', 'melon']
my_object = my_class(my_list)
vars(my_object) => {'pear': 'pear', 'melon': 'melon'}
```

Is there any method to automatically instantiate variables using list which might not be known at the time I write the code for the class?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe it is possible. You might have to settle for a `dict`

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, _list):
        for value in _list:
            setattr(self, value, value)
```

But you should not do this, what is your use case ?

Comment: I am using pydantic validation. I would like to pass a list of possible values to an enum class in pydantic and then validate using that class

Answer (score 0):

I could get no further than this code:

```
my_list = ["apple", "banana", "mango"]


class my_class:
    def __init__(self, my_list: list) -> None:
        pass

my_object = type("my_class", (), {k: k for k in my_list})
print(vars(my_object))
```

Comment: @Speedlulu, did it perfectly